# Move menu items to the right

Tags: html, css

I am working on code I got from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar and trying to modify it to fit my needs.

So far I have managed to make all my menu items work the way I want and get the styling right but I can't get the menu items to move to the right.

[image: right now]

Expected outcome:

[image: expected]

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #8FC3EA;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #8FC3EA;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="startTest.php">Issue Test</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Test Results 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="gradeTest.php">Grade Test</a>
      <a href="viewReport.php">View Report</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Admin 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="editTest.php">Edit Test</a>
      <a href="users.php">Users</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"><img src="userIcon.png" height="30" width="30"> 
      </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="changePassword.php">Change Password</a>
      <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `float: right;`

You will have to adjust your drop downs so they don't go off screen.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #8FC3EA;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #8FC3EA;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="right">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="startTest.php">Issue Test</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Test Results 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="gradeTest.php">Grade Test</a>
      <a href="viewReport.php">View Report</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Admin 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="editTest.php">Edit Test</a>
      <a href="users.php">Users</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"><img src="userIcon.png" height="30" width="30"> 
      </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="changePassword.php">Change Password</a>
      <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, adding the .right class helped and I was able to get everything over to the right.

But as you said I now need to adjust my drop down menus as they go off the screen.
I will work on this but I am fairly new to CSS so any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: This should point you in the right direction [https://stackoverflow.com/a/30466822/10997917](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30466822/10997917)

Answer (score 0):

Create another div inside your nav bar, and float it to the right, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>     
        body {
          font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        .navbar {
          width: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: #8FC3EA;
        }

        .nav-content {
            float : right ; 
        }

        .navbar a {
          float: left;
          font-size: 16px;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 10px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }

        .dropdown {
          float: left;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        .dropdown .dropbtn {
          font-size: 16px;  
          border: none;
          outline: none;
          color: white;
          padding: 10px;
          background-color: inherit;
          font-family: inherit;
          margin: 0;
        }

        .dropdown .dropbtn-right {
          position: absolute;
          right: 5px;
          font-size: 16px;  
          border: none;
          outline: none;
          color: white;
          padding: 10px;
          background-color: inherit;
          font-family: inherit;
          margin: 0;
        }

        .navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
          background-color: #8FC3EA;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: #f9f9f9;
          min-width: 160px;
          box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
          z-index: 1;
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
          float: none;
          color: black;
          padding: 12px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
          text-align: left;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
          background-color: #ddd;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
          display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="nav-content">
        <a href="#home">Home</a> <a href="startTest.php">Issue Test</a> 
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Test Results <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> </button> 
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="gradeTest.php">Grade Test</a> <a href="viewReport.php">View Report</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Admin <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> </button> 
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="editTest.php">Edit Test</a> <a href="users.php">Users</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn"><img src="userIcon.png" height="30" width="30"> </button> 
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="changePassword.php">Change Password</a> <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Kerri, I got this from ajzbc but now my issue is the drop downs run off the edge of the page

Comment: Sure! An easy way to do this would be to shift all your drop-downs to the left. So if you add this line to `.dropdown-content`, it will nudge the drop-downs leftward. `margin-left : -90px ; ` You can play with the distance and width -- and even customize it for each item -- but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Final code that thanks to ajzbc... now to add all the PHP so menu items only show for the right users, but I think I can make that work it's CSS I don't fully understand yet.

```css
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.right {
   float: right;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #8FC3EA;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #8FC3EA;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content-right {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content-right a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content-right {
  right: 4px;
  left: auto;
  display: block;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="right">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="startTest.php">Issue Test</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Test Results 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="gradeTest.php">Grade Test</a>
      <a href="viewReport.php">View Report</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Admin 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="editTest.php">Edit Test</a>
      <a href="users.php">Users</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"><img src="usricon.png" height="20" width="20"> 
      </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-right">
      <a href="changePassword.php">Change Password</a>
      <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```