# Multi level dropdown open to the left

Tags: html, css, sass, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have a multi-level dropdown but it opens to the right by default. I have tried to tweak it a lot but doesn't seem to work no matter what I try.
I'll provide the code here. The HTML might be a little messed up because I had to remove the rails code in there and only leave plain HTML.

The dropdowns open to the right and overflow the window. If anyone has a better way to do it, I am all ears.

[image]

```css
.dropdown-wrapper {
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    // background: #1bc2a2;
  }
  li>ul {
    margin-right: 190px;
  }
  ul li {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    color: goldenrod;
    float: left;
    min-width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    // background: #1bc2a2;
  }
  ul li:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid goldenrod;
  }
  li ul {
    display: none;
  }
  ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: goldenrod;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  ul li a:hover {
    background: #FAF9F6;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  ul li:hover {
    background: #FAF9F6;
  }
  li:hover>ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 2px;
  }
  .main-navigation {
    ul {
      background: white;
    }
  }
  li:hover li {
    float: none;
  }
  // li:hover a { background: #1bc2a2; }
  li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #FAF9F6;
  }
  .main-navigation li ul li {
    border-top: 0;
  }
  ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul:before,
  ul:after {
    content: " ";
    /* 1 */
    display: table;
    /* 2 */
  }
  ul:after {
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-navigation">
  <li>Treatments Provided
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
  </li>
  <li>2
    <ul>
      <li class="">
        <a href=>a</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Similar issue here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466706/dropdown-menu-to-the-left-side/30466822

Comment: @NajmiehSadatSafarabadi I have already tried that and it doesn't work well on my project. The child list jumps out of the parent list and makes it look all glitchy